# How to remove left-recursion in the following grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4, antlrworks

Unfortunately, it is not possible for **ANTLR** to support direct-left recursion when the rule has  parameters passed. The only viable option is to *remove the left recursion*. Is there a way to remove the left-recursion in the following grammar ?

---

```
a[int x]
    : b a[$x] c
    | a[$x - 1] 
    (
          c a[$x - 1]
        | b c
    )
    ;
```

---

The problem is in the second alternative involving left recursion. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the parameters and easier formatting, it would look like this:

```
a
 : b a c
 | a (c a | b c)
 ;
```

When `a`'s left recursive alternative is matched *n* times, it would just mean that `(c a | b c)` will be matched *n* times, pre-pended with the terminating `b a c` (the first alternative). That means that this rule will always start with `b a c`, followed by zero or more occurrences of `(c a | b c)`:

```
a
 : b a c (c a | b c)*
 ;
```